How is asking about the difference between 2 variants opinion-based?
Do chess960 and chess differ for reasons 'far beyond just opening theory'?
I'm simply asking what features of chess960 are there that make chess960 different from regular chess besides openings. I can't see how this is opinion-based anymore than asking the difference between eg 2 opening variations in regular chess. There's literally just the mathematical definitions of the pieces, how they move and their starting positions. I'm not asking if some positions are more 'beautiful' than others or something.

Actually, I'm taking this opportunity to follow-up on:

What is our criteria for deciding opinion-based questions? Are they applied consistently?

which is still unanswered. I actually had planned to make a whole other post on the matter. Afaik, the purpose of opinion-based is to avoid 'What's your favourite (...)?' kind of questions.
If you find this opinion-based, then I have a list of many more unclosed questions that are as well.
The main site post that started the above meta post is
Why is this question too opinion-based?
What are the general principles for playing hypermodern against hypermodern?
which was incorrectly closed by a moderator before 5 votes.

Unfortunately I make mistakes from time to time (read: often).
Looking back, I do not recall the specific reason the question struck me as opinion-based. I wish I could as I would explain it, even if I now don't see it the same way.
Reexamining the question, I think the question will essentially be soliciting Chess.SE opinions as I don't think most users have the chess skill to truly answer this question.  However, it also seems clear we can't be closing every question as opinion-based if there's not a super GM to answer it.
If I made a mistake on this one, please forgive.
